# Play Framework 2.4/2.5 : Add customized internationalization messages from the database

Tags: playframework

I need to load (replace) some message keys from the database without restarting the application. The aim is to let super-admin of the page to be able to change (override) the default texts if needed.

Where the new keys come from is not important, but I don't know actually how to do the implementation. I use Java. Do you have some similar working example or ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is exactly your doubt? You don't know how to load the values from database? Or you don't know how to disable the default module and enable yours? Or how to refresh the messages when they change?

Comment: Hi, I actually didn't know how to do that in Play at all. After time i got to that point that I need to create my module (extend original I18Module and its DefaultMessagesApi) in Scala. I still use original messages for default texts but created administration where you can override them.

Comment: Hi, I am new to Scala and have a similar requirement. If you have implemented this, please guide me on how to achieve this. If possible, please provide a few code samples.

Comment: Hi, I did solve it with Message API plugin, loading the message keys from the message files as default and then overriding with records in database. I can provide you the code examples, just write me PM.